# VS Code - python cannot open extention file no such file or directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip

I am using python in Visual Studio Code and need to install notebook. When I clicked the install button popped up

[image]

it just gives me the error saying no such file or directory. The file is actually in the directory but the path doesn't look right because there are no slashes separating the file names.

[image]

The actual path is supposed to be C:\Users\ningm.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.8.108011\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py where I can actually find the file

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you use Jupyter notebook function in VSCode before? After what steps did you take, screenshot 1 popped up? Since the Jupyter notebook function in VSCode is provided by the python extension, it is recommended that you could try to reinstall the python extension.

Comment: Although I've been using VS code for years, this is the first time I use VS Code for Jupyter notebook function. I always had Python extension installed and normal .py code can run without a problem. When I used VS code to open up a .ipynb file, screenshot 1 popped up reminding me to install notebook, and when I clicked install, the following error in screenshot 2 showed up.

Comment: Have you tried using other versions of python extensions? Check whether the Python "Scripts" folder has been added to the user environment variables (For example: D:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\). In addition, you could also try to install Jupyter manually The required package. (**pip install ipykernel**)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using bash as your cmd prompt this worked for me on windows 10.

Type "powershell" into the cmd prompt to open the powershell prompt. Then just pip install ipykernel or try to open the file in vs code and it will prompt you to install it. Once complete just enter "exit" into the powershell prompt to get back to bash.